# How To Calculate ETA Between Two Lat and Long in Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps

I am using Google Map in one of my Application. 
in `Driver_location` table each driver current location is being updated periodically with driver_id, latitude and longitude value.Below is my `driver_location` data table structure

[image]

From above table I am getting nearest 5 drivers by below code in laravel

```
 $nearest_carbid = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
        ->having('distance', '<=', 5)
        ->where('driver_location.status','Online')
        ->where('driver_location.car_id',$car_id)
        ->limit(5)->get();
```

and getting nearest driver_id's from above by below loop with user requested `pickup_latitude` and `pickup_longitude`

```
 $data = [];
        foreach ($nearest_carbid as $key => $value) {

         $data[] = [
        'pickup_latitude'     => $pickup_latitude,
        'pickup_longitude'   =>  $pickup_longitude,
        'driver_id'     =>   $value->user_id, // each driver_id from driver location table
```

what i want to do is calculate eta in minutes for each `$value->user_id` from `$pickup_latitude` and `$pickup_longitude` like below

[image]

how can i achieve this using google map api

Answer (score -1):

The issue you have here is that you have the distance of the drivers from the user *in a straight line.*

I could be right across from you, but on the other side of the river, and it could suggest to you that I am the closest driver, but in reality, I have to drive 5 km down the road to find a bridge to get across the river.

Additionally, your caclulation will return the distance in a straight line and will not account for the real distance you need to travel if you were following the roads etc, so you cannot even use an average speed to get the ETA.

In reality, I would suggest you use Google Maps API, or a similar service, to get the distance that they would actually need to travel. You can then augment this with either an average speed for the area they are in to guess an ETA, or you could use the same (or a different) service to be able to query an ETA. Google Maps is fairly accurate, taking into account current traffic conditions, time of day etc, however this is just an opinion.

If none of the above work for you, you will simply need to derive an average speed that you think accounts for the variation in distance that the driver will need to travel in reality and use that along with the distance they need to go to work out the time it will take to travel that distance.

Comment: how can I achieve this using google map api, I am currently using google map for getting lat and lng

Comment: @Mithu the Google Distance Matrix API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) is probably what you are after. They have PHP SDKs, although you may find a Laravel specific package also. Usually they allow you to give a departing and arriving location, along with the mode of transport and they'll return the route options and ETAs.